# ASCII text based grid building

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to build an ASCII text based grid in python 3.

I have multiple `lists` of items (each with a name and a tuple containing its location, in `(x,y)` coordinate form). I need to be able to build the grid, place each item at its respective location, and also be able to move each item.

Any hints on how to get started?

Comment: Please add some demo values. It's helpful to solve.

Comment: Try with arrays, or nested lists. See http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-python